# Iĝi en "bona sana formo"

Tags: single-word-requests

Kiel oni diras:

- (EN) It is good to get in shape
- (FR) C'est bien de se mettre en forme
- (EO) ?

Eble ĉi tiuj:

1. Estas bone formiĝi
2. Estas bone iĝi en fizika taŭgeco
3. Estas bone fizika-taŭgeciĝi
4. Estas bone bonstatiĝi

[aĉaĵoj, abomenaĵoj]

Dankon pro via helpo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fizike/korpe bonfarti` povas taŭgi kiel traduko de "to be in good shape".

Vi do povus sufiĉe rekte traduki per:

```
Estas bone ...
  pli bone farti fizike
  plibonigi vian fizikan/korpan farton
```

Sed eblas ankaŭ pli simpla traduko, kiu tamen gardas la signifon:

```
Estas bone ekzerci sian korpon
```

Se temus pri iu specifa taŭgeco, ekzemple esti fizike bonfarta por povi fini dek kilometran kunkuron, oni povas aldoni tiun celon fine:

```
fizike/korpe bonfarta por ...
ekzerci sian korpon por ...
```